# How to treat zero values as true using php?

Tags: php, is-empty

Here is my sample code:

```
$issue_id = $_POST['issue_id'];
if(!empty($issue_id)){
  echo 'true';
}
else{
   echo 'false';
}
```

If I pass `0 to $_POST['issue_id']` by form submitting then it echo false. Which I want is: Condition will be true if the following conditions are fulfilled:
1. true when I pass any value having 0.
2. false when I don't pass any value. i.e:  `$_POST['issue_id']` is undefined.

I also tried this:

```
if(!isset($issue_id)){
  echo 'true';
}
else{
   echo 'false';
}


if(!empty($issue_id) || $issue==0){
  echo 'true';
}
else{
   echo 'false';
}
```

The last one is okay, meaning if I pass any value having ZERO then it will echo true. But it will also echo true if I don't pass any value. Any idea?

Comment: Be careful of `empty()`. Despite the name, it doesn’t check whether the variable is actually _empty_ — just whether it’s falsey. `null`, 0, false and an empty array, for example, are all considered “empty” in this sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The last is okay, meaning if I pass any value having ZERO then it echo true. But it also echo true if I don't pass any value. Any idea?

```
if (isset($_POST["issue_id"]) && $_POST["issue_id"] !== "") {
}
```

please notice I used `!==` not `!=`. this is why:

```
0 == "" // true
0 === "" // false
```

See more at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

---

also if you are expecting number you can use

```
if (isset($_POST["issue_id"]) && is_numeric($_POST["issue_id"])) {
}
```

since `is_numeric("")` returns false

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

---

Alternatively if you expect number good option is `filter_var`

```
if (isset($_POST["issue_id"]) {
   $issue_id = filter_var($_POST["issue_id"], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
   if ($issue_id !== false) { 
   }
}
```

since `filter_var("", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` will returns false and `filter_var("0", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` will return `(int) 0`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score -1):

When you get data from a form, remember:

- All text boxes, whether `input` or `textarea` will come as **strings**. That includes empty text boxes, and text boxes which contain numbers.
- All *selected* buttons will have a value, but buttons which are not selected will *not be present at all*. This includes radio buttons, check boxes and actual buttons.

This means that `$_POST['issue_id']` will be the string `'0'`, which is actually truthy.

If you need it to be an integer, use something like: `$issue_id=intval($_POST['issue_id'])`;

Comment: @Peter The `@` operator exists for a reason. Judicious use of it would be to use it when you can handle the error in your stride, and where the absence of the value is otherwise harmless. In this case, a missing POST value shouldn’t be a deal breaker. I do agree that over using it is dangerous.

Comment: there is many things that exists in PHP but it's bad practice to use them. Supressing errors no matter where is unarguably bad practice. In your case you are basically too lazy to use `isset`

Comment: Also **error messages exists for a reason**. There is countless number of articles about it https://www.sitepoint.com/why-suppressing-notices-is-wrong/

Answer (score -1):

```
if(isset($_POST['issue_id'])) {
  if($_POST['issue_id'] == 0) {
    echo "true";
  }
  else {
   echo "false";
  }
}
```

Comment: it will echo true for empty string `""`

Comment: I really probably shouldn't be commenting this time of night. LOL
However, if it's empty when the form is submitted, the issue_id variable is not going to exist. Unless something else in the code sets $_POST['issue_id'] after the form is posted, then my code works as expected.

Comment: @Difster In the absence of an explanation from @Peter, presuming the data comes from a text box, then `$_POST['issue_id']` will have the value of an empty string — all text boxes are sent, even if they are empty. However, your code would work better if you test `$_POST['issue_id'] === 0`, since an empty string and 0 are __equal__ but not __identical__; that is, one can be converted to the other.

Comment: @Manngo `$_POST['issue_id'] === 0` would return false since $_POST values are always strings

Comment: @Peter Yes, you’re right. I should have said something more generic such as “test `$something===0` since etc”. Using `$_POST['issue_id']` was definitely a bad example.

Answer (score -1):

@Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan you can also full fill your two condition like below one:

```
<?php
$_POST["issue_id"] = "0";
$issue_id = isset($_POST['issue_id']) ? (!empty($_POST['issue_id']) || $_POST['issue_id'] === 0 || $_POST['issue_id'] === "0")  ? true : false : false;
if($issue_id){
  echo 'true';
}
else{
   echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: it returns true on `""`

Comment: Now it returns false on `"0"`. Just please see my naswer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43387287/994054

Comment: now check @Peter updated one and tell is there any case remains ?

Comment: `$_POST['issue_id'] === 0` will never happen

Comment: y ? it wont happen and tell is this not suitable answer for above question or you don't want to accept my answer ? if this is so then its ok @Peter i can understand

Comment: i am not the one who asked question