# Possible to make a zero be true?

Tags: php, string

I have a string:

```
$string = '0';
```

And in an echo statement like this:

```
echo ($string ? 'true':'false');
```

I want the `'0'` to be *true*. It currently is *false*.

Is there a way to **adjust the echo statement**? I know I can for example add a space in the string:

```
$string = ' 0';
```

And it will be *true*. But I am hoping for a solution that doesn't require me adjusting the string.

Comment: `$string === '0'`?

Comment: @AlonEitan How do you mean? Note that I do not want to adjust the string variable, unless if that is the only option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to treat zero values as true using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387096/how-to-treat-zero-values-as-true-using-php)

Comment: Does this helps you? https://www.php.net/manual/fr/types.comparisons.php

Comment: @HenrikPetterson I only changed the condition, not the string

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to adjust the echo statement?

No - not without editing PHP's source code and rebuilding it yourself. The `echo` statement in PHP has 20-year-old  well-documented behaviour - it would be foolish to make your PHP environment incompatible with the rest of the PHP ecosystem just to save yourself a few keystrokes.

A better idea is just to add your own global function:

```
<?php

function zeroToBoolText( $str ) {
    if( !is_string( $str ) ) die( "Argument is not a string." );
    if( $str === '0' ) {
        return 'true';
    }
    else {
        return ( $str ? 'true' : 'false' );
    }
}

?>
```

Used like so:

```
$string = '0';

echo zeroToBoolText( $string );
```

Comment: So essentially, this would work: `echo ($string || $string === '0' ? 'true':'false');`

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Have you tested it?

Comment: i have naukri, freshersworld too @HenrikPetterson

Answer (score 0):

Using the below condition you can change if string is 0 true..

```
    if($string === '0')
    {
        $string = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $string = false;
    }
```

Try it, i think you need this one thank you..

Comment: It's important to use the exactly-equal-to operator `===` instead of the approximately-equal-to operator `==` in PHP - otherwise your posted code won't work the way OP wants it to.

Comment: Just replace that exact-equal-to operator, it will return a correct result : - )